# A BigInteger class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, bigint

I made this project to practice object-oriented programming. I have implemented `operator+` and `operator+=`. The rationale behind `struct cache` are

1. I don't necessarily need to traverse the entire container to display the value.
2. Using a `struct cache` makes it possible to modify its value even in a const method

I also considered eliminating the container entirely and representing `BigInt` as a string, that might have been a better approach.

Here is my code

### BigInt.h

```
#ifndef BIGINTEGER_H_
#define BIGINTEGER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

namespace MyBigInteger
{ 
    struct cache
    {
        bool has_changed{true};
        std::string cache_value{""};
    };

    class BigInt
    {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& bigint);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, BigInt& bigint);
        public:
            BigInt();
            explicit BigInt(const std::string &str_number);
            BigInt& operator+=(const BigInt& rhs);
            BigInt operator+(const BigInt& lhs) const;
            size_t size() const;
        private:
            cache* string_rep;
            size_t bigint_size;
            std::deque<int8_t> elems;

            std::string get_new_cache_value() const;
    };

    int8_t to_digit(const char chr);
    char to_char(const int value);
}

#endif
```

### BigInt.cpp

```
#include "BigInt.h"

#include <algorithm>

namespace MyBigInteger
{
    BigInt::BigInt()
        : string_rep{new cache{false, ""}} {}

    BigInt::BigInt(const std::string& str_number)
        : string_rep{new cache{false, str_number}}, bigint_size{str_number.size()}
        {
            for(const auto chr : str_number)
                elems.push_back(to_digit(chr));
        }
        
    int8_t to_digit(const char chr)
    {
        return chr - '0';
    }

    char to_char(const int value)
    {
        return value + '0';
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& bigint)
    {
        if(bigint.string_rep->has_changed)
        {
            bigint.string_rep->cache_value = bigint.get_new_cache_value();
            bigint.string_rep->has_changed = false;
        }

        os << bigint.string_rep->cache_value;

        return os;
    }

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, BigInt& bigint)
    {
        is >> bigint.string_rep->cache_value;

        return is;
    }

    std::string BigInt::get_new_cache_value() const
    {
        std::string temp_str;
        std::for_each(elems.cbegin(), elems.cend(), [&](const int x)
        { temp_str += to_char(x); });

        return temp_str;
    }

    BigInt& BigInt::operator+=(const BigInt& rhs)
    {
        *this = std::move(*this + rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    BigInt BigInt::operator+(const BigInt& rhs) const
    {
        BigInt res;
        res.string_rep = new cache{true, ""};
        unsigned total = 0;
        unsigned carry = 0;

        auto beg = elems.crbegin(), rhs_beg = rhs.elems.crbegin();
        for(; beg != elems.crend() && rhs_beg != rhs.elems.crend();
            ++beg, ++rhs_beg)
        {
            total = *beg + *rhs_beg + carry;
            carry = total / 10;
            res.elems.push_front(total % 10);
        }
        
        if(beg == elems.crend() && rhs_beg == rhs.elems.crend())
            return res;

        else if(beg == elems.crend())
        {
            for(; rhs_beg != rhs.elems.crend(); ++rhs_beg)
            {
                total = *rhs_beg + carry;
                carry = total / 10;
                res.elems.push_front(total % 10);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(; beg != elems.crend(); ++beg)
            {
                total = *beg + carry;
                carry = total / 10;
                res.elems.push_front(total % 10);
            }
        }
        if(carry)
            res.elems.push_front(carry);

        return res;
    }

    size_t BigInt::size() const
    {
        return bigint_size;
    }
}
```

### main.cpp

````
#include "BigInt.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace MyBigInteger;

int main()
{
    BigInt my_bigint{"123456789123456789123456789"};
    BigInt my_bigint2{"24682468246824682468"};
    std::cout << "my_bigint + my_bigint2: " << my_bigint + my_bigint2 << '\n'; 
    my_bigint += my_bigint2;
    std::cout << "my_bigint after my_bigint += my_bigint2: " << my_bigint << '\n';

    BigInt my_bigint3{};
    std::cout << "default my_bigint3: " << my_bigint3 << '\n';
    std::cin >> my_bigint3;
    std::cout << "my_bigint3 after input: " << my_bigint3 << '\n';
    BigInt my_bigint4{my_bigint3};
    std::cout << "After copy constructor: " << my_bigint4 << '\n';
    my_bigint4 = my_bigint;
    std::cout << "After copy assignment: " << my_bigint4 << '\n';
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

### Use `constexpr`

These functions

```cpp
    int8_t to_digit(const char chr)
    {
        return chr - '0';
    }

    char to_char(const int value)
    {
        return value + '0';
    }
```

can be marked `constexpr`. You are telling that it is possible to calculate the value at compile-time. `constexpr` also implies `inline`, resulting in faster execution time. Note that after marking it `constexpr` you must define it with the declaration.

---

### Use `string_view`

As your class name suggests, you are going to be working with **big** numbers, i.e **big** strings will come. In that case, copying can be very bad and slow.

In your class constructor

```cpp
     BigInt::BigInt(const std::string& str_number)
        : string_rep{new cache{false, str_number}}, bigint_size{str_number.size()}
        {
            for(const auto chr : str_number)
                elems.push_back(to_digit(chr));
        }
```

I refactored it for this example

```cpp
struct cache
{
    std::string str;
};

struct BigInt
{
    cache c;

    BigInt(const std::string& str)
        : c{ str.data() }
}
```

Assuming there is no small string optimization, you will be calling `new` 2 times, once for constructing `str`, and the other time for copying into `c.str`.

However, if you use `string_view`

```cpp
struct cache
{
    std::string str;
};

struct BigInt
{
    cache c;

    BigInt(std::string_view str)
        : c{str.data()}
    {}

};
```

You will be calling `new` only once, to construct the string and that same string into the member.

---

### TODO

Here are some things that you left out as far as I can remember

- Operators - `-,*,/,%,^,&,~,|, ==, ++, --`
- Casting - Decide whether your data type should be able to cast to the primitive ones, or the opposite

Comment: I would implement those `operators`, I just wanted review of what I have done so far.

Comment: Adding `inline` is reductant, the compiler should be smart enough to select what to inline, but great review.

Comment: @theProgrammer Yes surely, but the compiler can't inline your original function since the declaration and definition are split